# Changing CSS breaks Javascript Focus() Method

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an Input Field, with an Edit button and whenever I push the Edit button I have my javascript focus on the Input field like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8bm9w7n/

Next thing is that I want to hide the Input field to appear dynamically, using CSS, by using the Vue v-class directive, which also works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8bm9w7n/1/

Only thing I have changed is the CSS in the .editInputField Class from **display block**, to **display none**.

```
.editInputField {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Now the Inputfield appears dynamically, but the focus() does not work and I have no idea why. Does anyone have any suggestion?

For anyone prefering CodePen:

Working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jdgozw

Non working example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNXyEz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `focus()` call in a `$nextTick` handler since (in production mode) changes to the DOM normally take place in a batch process after the Model changes.

Here's an updated CodePen that works:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPXNXN

The key change is:

```
        editTask: function (that) {
            this.editedTodo = that.todo;

            this.$nextTick(function () {
              that.$$.editInputField.focus();
            });
        },
```

For more info on `$nextTick` see: http://vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html

Comment: Thank you David. You've got any idea, why the focus() method puts the cursor at the beginning of the Input field, instead of at the end?

Comment: You have to work with the input's selection: http://www.sitepoint.com/jqueryhtml5-input-focus-cursor-positions/